# Composite primary key and slow queries

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS codes (
    code       character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    used       boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    user_id    integer NOT NULL,
    order_id   integer,
    created    timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code, user_id)
  );
```

And I have simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "count" 
FROM "codes" "code" 
WHERE "code"."user_id" = {some_id} 
 AND "code"."order_id" IS NULL;
```

Which is very slow, explain analyze:

```
'Aggregate  (cost=3576.10..3576.11 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1471.870..1471.871 rows=1 loops=1)'
'  ->  Seq Scan on codes (cost=0.00..3323.89 rows=50443 width=17) (actual time=0.139..203.139 rows=49998 loops=1)'
'        Filter: ((order_id IS NULL) AND (user_id = 10))'
'        Rows Removed by Filter: 116498'
'Planning Time: 1.450 ms'
'Execution Time: 1471.981 ms'
```

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Your query criteria are not covered by the primary key.  If you need to optimize this query, then index the `user_id` column or if that is not good enough, then `(user_id, order_id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index can only be used efficiently if the *first index column* is used in the `WHERE` condition (yes, I know there are exceptions, but it is a good rule of thumb).

So to support that query, you should define the primary key the other way around, as `(user_id, code)`. That will guarantee the constraint just as well, but the underlying index will support your query.

If you cannot change the primary key like that, you need another index on `user_id` alone.

But then, looking on the `Rows Removed by Filter`, probably a sequential scan is the fastest access strategy, and an index won't help at all. Try it out.

Comment: single index on user_id just makes things worse, but when i changed order of keys to (user_id, code) it's now working waaay faster. ty